# Unity make rounded corner on radial circle bar?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Ok, Im using this script and an image having successfully made an unwinding circle in unity:

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

```
circle2.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(currentValue * 6.28f), Mathf.Cos(currentValue * 6.28f), 0f) * 1;

if (currentValue < 100) {
    currentValue += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    //ProgressIndicator.text = ((int)currentValue).ToString () + "%";
    //LoadingText.SetActive (true);
}

LoadingBar.fillAmount = currentValue / 100;
```

Im trying to make something like Apple Watch circles where the end caps are rounded. To do this, they said here to position a circle at the end of the stroke using the vector3 they listed:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-rounded-circular-bar.461067/

This doesn't work. How can I position the circle wherever the end of the unwinding stroke/part of the circle is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sin and Cos functions deliver values from range <0, 1>. That might be too little to place an element on GUI.

At the end of the following expression, try to replace one with some bigger values.

```
Vector3(Mathf.Sin(currentValue * 6.28f), Mathf.Cos(currentValue * 6.28f), 0f) * /*replace this: */ 1;
```

The key is to adjust it to the radius of your circle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using

```
circle2.transform.position
```

For UI objects. This sets position in global coordinates

To place UI objects you can use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps and can clear it up:

```
 currentLerpTimeScan += Time.deltaTime;
 if (currentLerpTimeScan > lerpTime)
 {
    currentLerpTimeScan = lerpTime;
 }

 float perc = currentLerpTimeScan / lerpTime;
 perc = Mathf.Sin(perc * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
 RadialImageScan.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(startValueScan, endValueScan, perc);

 currentValue = RadialImageScan.fillAmount;

 ScanCircle.localPosition = 
 (new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(currentValue * 6.28f), 
 Mathf.Cos(currentValue * 6.28f)) * scanMultiplier) * -1; 
 // remove -1 if you wish this depends on ui setup
```